# Getting Ubuntu Core Mir-Kiosk to pass login credentials

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-core, kiosk, mir

I'm trying to build a Zabbix NOC-type display screen for our office on a Raspberry Pi 3, using Ubuntu Core 22, and the ubuntu-frame and wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk snaps, per the info here - https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/make-a-secure-ubuntu-web-kiosk/29335 -

However I need to get the mir-kiosk tool to pass (or retain) login credentials for the Zabbix server so that it shows the correct dashboard we have created for the NOC display. We have several units with different NOC display requirements, so we have a user for each, so we can't just use the public no-login disdplay.

Any pointers or alternatives please?

Many thanks,
James